# Is there a Scratch-like Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, ide

I believe that the answer is no, but I wanted to check before I put effort into rectifying it (and no, no promises!)

Is there anything like [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu) that one can use to program an Arduino?

(Scratch is a graphical coding environment that makes learning to program fun, and is certainly suitable for elementary students.  It is put out by the Lifelong Kindergarten Group at MIT).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the works. A friend of mine, Ed Baafi, is working on a Scratch-like
interface for Arduino. I believe he may be presenting something in Cambridge (MA) at the
science festival this April.

Using a python shell script we (by we I mean Ed) were able to interface
one of my USB+XBee interfaces with the my ZB1 (arduino compatible board + XBee).
Text typed into an entry box was displayed on an LCD.

His site is http://www.modk.it

Comment: Wow!  I'm going to have to look into that some more.

Comment: There also mention of Dave Mellis doing some work with Scratch
for Arduino -- See http://web.media.mit.edu/~mellis/

Comment: It should be noted that the project Ed Baafi is working on is Modkit.  (Another answer has more details).

Answer (score 5):

There is a program called Catenary that allows Scratch programs to talk to an Arduino board.

There are more details and a user guide found here:
http://scratchconnections.wik.is/User:Chalkmarrow/Catenary

Comment: That's interesting.  Interesting indeed.

Comment: Scratch will communicate with other programs via sockets!  That's amazing!

Comment: It is easier to use Catenary with Build Your Own Blocks.  See http://robotclub.ab.ca/blog/27/code-blocks-electronic-bricks-and-lego-beams

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed at some length (for AVRs) here:

http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=484219

Answer (score 3):

**Modkit**

> Modkit is an in-browser graphical
>   programming environment for little
>   devices called embedded systems.
>   Modkit can currently program **Arduino**
>   and Arduino compatible hardware using
>   simple graphical blocks similar to and
>   heavily inspired by the **Scratch**
>   programming environment developed by
>   the Lifelong Kindergarten Group at the
>   MIT Media Lab.

[Modkit](http://www.modk.it/) 
[Screenshot 1](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_edUeWfBB4Kg/TI8NoUehCFI/AAAAAAAAAGU/XccnX6QRwbQ/s1600/modkit_danger_expanded_screenshot-755x600.png) 
[Screenshot 2](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_edUeWfBB4Kg/TI8L_EsE2iI/AAAAAAAAAGE/bzXKJtE3WO4/s1600/modkit_danger_screenshot-755x600.png)

Answer (score 2):

In Tinkercad there is a circuit function where you can place the arduino and all the other necessary components and program the virtual arduino using a scratch like interface. You can then copy the code on to the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Interesting.  Not a bad selection of components either: the usual common IO devices, standard passive components, transistors, relays, comparators, timers, logic gates ... no schematic view, unfortunately, which would have been nice, but I guess given the target market that's probably a bit too much to expect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cypress PSoC chips are programmed with a [visual dataflow style IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSoC).

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately, it does not look like something I can leverage for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Scratch for Arduino (S4A) http://s4a.cat/ is one of them

Answer (score 0):

Just learned about another simplified programming environment for the Arduino: [Minibloq](http://blog.minibloq.org/).